# Getting json with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl, instagram

Is this the correct way to get a json response from an URL with Zend? I'm trying to get information from the Instagram API by the way (http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

```
    public function getAccessToken($code) {
                $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');    
                $client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token');
                $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
                $client->setParameterPost('client_id', $config['social']['instagram']['client_id']);
                $client->setParameterPost('client_secret', $config['social']['instagram']['client_secret']);
                $client->setParameterPost('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
                $client->setParameterPost('redirect_uri', $config['social']['instagram']['redirect_uri']);
                $client->setParameterPost('code', $code);
                $body = $client->request();
                return $body->getBody();
}
```

I'm just getting a strange response, something like:

```
string '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 


<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <title>Instagram</title> 
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320px">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/master-new.css?1" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8"> 
</head> 
<body> 

    <div id="wrap" class="grid-all group"> 

<div style'... (length=726)
```

Any ideas? I'm a bit of a noob in Zend by the way so please make sure you think about the very obvious too :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by outputting the values of all of the fields in `$config['social']['instagram']` and see if they are correctly set. I think they may not be properly set and instagram is sending back a generic response.

Also if $config was loaded into the registry as `Zend_Config_Ini` or `Zend_Config_Xml` I believe it's an object so you would have to get the values by saying `$config->social->instagram->client_id`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but that's not the issue, the values are fine, in fact if I set one of them incorrectly on purpose I do get the instagram message of it being incorrect